# jformattedtextfield rounded numbers

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

i have a JFormattedTextField , and i want that when i try to enter a number, example 1002 , that i will rounded to the nearest multiple of 5

1002->1000

304->305

6->5

9->10

1->0

etc..

i've already setup a number format to cancel the grouping, and accepting only numbers

```
NumberFormat format=NumberFormat.getInstance();
format.setGroupingUsed(false);
pun1[i]=new JFormattedTextField(format); //pun1 and pun2 are the arrays of FIELDS
pun2[i]=new JFormattedTextField(format);
```

how can i resolve this problem?

I want this editing inside the field, while i'm writing the number, just as when the grouping character appears!

Answer (score 0):

This works for `int` arguments:

```
public int roundToClosestFive(int num) {
    return (int) (Math.round(num / 5.0) * 5);
}
```

Remember, to get the `int` value of the string you've entered you can do: `Integer.valueOf(string);` and pass that as an argument to the method. To have the text inside the `JFormattedTextField` change on focus change or enter, you could call the above method from the `propertyChange()` method of a `PropertyChange` listener that you can add to the `JTextFormattedTextField`. Something like this in the `propertyChange()` method:

```
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == pun1[i]) {
        ((JFormattedTextField) source).setText(""
                + roundToClosestFive(((Number)pun1[i].getValue()).intValue()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I want this change during the edit of the field, so i'm writing "1003" and the number inside the field change to 1005

Comment: Ok, I've added to my answer. Does that work for you? Again, for the above case, you'd have to move focus away from the `JTextFormattedField` or hit enter for the text inside the field to change.

Comment: nope , it doesn't work :\
if not JTextFormattedField, what do you suggest?

Comment: ok , i've solved , using the method setValue , and not setText :)